# I want to calculate the mean spark sql using python?

Tags: pyspark, mean, apache-spark-sql

showing out .count() , but goes wrong for .sum() , what shout I do ?

the code:

```
def meanTemperature(df,spark):
    counttemp=spark.sql("SELECT temperature  from washing").count()
    sumtemp=spark.sql("SELECT temperature from washing").sum()
    mean=sumtemp/counttemp
    return mean
```

the Error :
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sum'

Answer (score 0):

The sum() function is not available in DataFrame, hence the error. You can use the following snippet to find the mean value or median value.

```
meanTemp = spark.sql("select mean(temperature,0.5) from washing")
return meanTemp.collect()[0][0]
```

If you want to median value

```
medianTemp = spark.sql("select percentile_approx(temperature,0.5) from washing")
return medianTemp.collect()[0][0]
```